# How to prove that there exists any non negative integral solution to this equation

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, determinant

How do I prove that there always exists at least one non-negative integral solution for all $c$ in equation:
$det\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
y & x
\end{bmatrix}=c$

with bounds

$0 \leq a, b \leq A$

$0 \leq x, y \leq X$

$0 \leq c \leq AX$

Where $a,b,c,x,y, A, X$ are all integers.

I have tried using Bezout's Identity but it didn't work.